# Django group up by foreign keys

Tags: python, django

So i have two models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=200)

class Like(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='likes',  on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

What I want is to get the total number of `base` products (<5 likes), `standard` products (<10 likes) and `premium` products.

I don't know how I should count FK of each product and then group them; and preferably in 1 query.

`python` 3.6, `django` 2.1, `posgtresql`

Comment: Do you want to just get the count of `base`, `standard`, and `premium` products in one query?

Comment: @RieljunLiguid yes.

Comment: @ArtemDanilov the 1 query restriction seems impossible to me, because you should query 2 DB table `Product` and `Like`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how that should be acomplished in a single query, but you could try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
qs = Product.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count('like'))

base_products = qs.filter(num_likes__lt=5)
standard_products = qs.filter(num_likes__gte=5, num_likes__lt=10)
premium_products = qs.filter(num_likes__gte=10)
```

This code gives you 3 `QuerySet` objects with the data you asked for.

---

If you want a single database query (it still includes both tables in the query) but don't mind loading the data in python lists instead of querysets (needs more memory and maybe even more time), then you could try:

```
from django.db.models import Count
qs = Product.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count('like'))

base_products = []
standard_products = []
premium_products = []
for p in qs:
    if p.num_likes < 5:
        base_products.append(p)
    elif p.num_likes < 5:
        standard_products.append(p)
    else:
        premium_products.append(p)
```